# check_mysql_health - how to check non numeric output

Tags: mysql, nagios, icinga

I'm trying to check mysql queries output and compare the result with some values for my Nagios services checks.
It can be that there is a better way to resolve this (and if so - please share :))...
For now, I'm trying this method:

```
./check_mysql_health --username root --password MyPassw0rd --mode sql --name 'show variables like 'max_connections'' --name2 "max_connections 4096"
```

PS: my max_connections is 4096

```
mysql -Bse "show variables like 'max_connections';"
max_connections 4096
```

The output is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $value in numeric gt (>) at ./check_mysql_health line 1237.
    Use of uninitialized value $value in numeric gt (>) at ./check_mysql_health line 1238.
    OK - max_connections 4096:
```

And if I change the value in name2 to something not equal to "max_connections 4096", like "G1Li" the output returns with OK status.

```
    ./check_mysql_health --username root --password MyPassw0rd --mode sql --name 'show variables like 'max_connections'' --name2 "G1Li" 
Use of uninitialized value $value in numeric gt (>) at ./check_mysql_health 

line 1237.
    Use of uninitialized value $value in numeric gt (>) at ./check_mysql_health line 1238.
    OK - g1li:
# echo $?
0
```

Any ideas?

Gili

Comment: Probably this: `--name 'show variables like 'max_connections''`. The quotes "inside" that sql are terminating the bash string, so `--name` parameter ENDS at `like`, making max_connections etc... something completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to this this may help,

```
./check_mysql_health --username root --password MyPassw0rd --mode sql \
--name 'show 1,variables like 'max_connections'' --name2 "status max_connections 4096"
```

We are using this for Oracle. I am not sure about that status, but that 1 is correct.

Or you can customize like adding some more mode(There are two major parts one is for remote/local execution of sql query and another is parsing the result data for nagios/icinga ) in that plugin as you want!! That will be a better solution.